# Confused about how I execute a PhantomJS file. Beginner needing advice. [MacOS]

Tags: phantomjs

I'm currently trying to execute the hello.js example file in my Terminal but an completely failing to do so. The examples, I've found online either ask me to type:

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

my terminal returns

```
Can't open 'hello.js'
```

Or the absolute file path which for me is

```
/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/share/phantomjs/examples/hello.js
```

my terminal returns

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/share/phantomjs/examples/hello.js: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong here? :(

Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVt5o.png)

Comment: **Thanks for responding! Terminal returns + other similar lines:**
total 488
drwxr-xr-x  48 usernamehere  staff   1536 27 Jul 14:31 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 usernamehere  staff    128 27 Jul 14:05 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 usernamehere  staff   6148 27 Jul 14:31 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 usernamehere  staff   1671 24 Jan  2016 colorwheel.js
-rw-r--r--   1 usernamehere  staff    226 24 Jan  2016 countdown.js
-rw-r--r--   1 usernamehere  staff   1774 24 Jan  2016 detectsniff.js
-rw-r--r--   1 usernamehere  staff    286 24 Jan  2016 fibo.js
-rw-r--r--   1 usernamehere  staff     60 24 Jan  2016 hello.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the file in Phantomjs, you either need to supply phantomjs with the full path to the file:

```
phantomjs /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/share/phantomjs/examples/hello.js
```

or you can make life a little easier on yourself by copying the `examples` directory to somewhere easy to access (e.g. your home directory)

```
cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/share/phantomjs/examples ~/
```

(`~/` is a shortcut to your home directory; you could use the Finder to the `examples` directory to your home directory)

changing to that directory in Terminal

```
cd ~/examples
```

and then running

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

Comment: Holy crap! You're amazing. Thank you so much. Now working.